# Trying to get Shiny R app to run as a single instance

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with UI and Server functions that runs well.  For each prospective user a new instance is launched and then each person/instance work independently as designed.

I now want to provide training to online users of the app by working from a single instance so that any users input can be replicated on other users instance.  Question is that possible/practical and how should I think about refreshing for each online user when one user changes an input?

Comment: Are you asking about an app where users can interact with a common data and the change each one of them makes is visibile or affect others?

Comment: Yes. More specifically I read in a csv file, then modify this data based on user inputs and then output charts based on modified data. Can more than one user share a session and edit inputs/observe results from a single instance?